# mySQL query for return all rows based on latest Dates from row

Tags: mysql

Prices are updated 3 times per Date but I want to make a line graph and therefore need the latest price per date.

Below is what I have now.

```
select * from test_stock

Date                Name    Price   
2021-04-27 09:00:00 Vestas  510 
2021-04-27 10:00:00 Vestas  520 
2021-04-27 11:00:00 Vestas  515 
2021-04-26 09:00:00 Vestas  495
2021-04-26 10:00:00 Vestas  498
2021-04-26 11:00:00 Vestas  480     
2021-04-23 09:00:00 Vestas  495 
2021-04-23 10:00:00 Vestas  487
2021-04-23 11:00:00 Vestas  497
```

But this is what I aim for.

```
2021-04-27 11:00:00 Vestas  515 
2021-04-26 11:00:00 Vestas  480
2021-04-23 11:00:00 Vestas  497
```

How can I make this return the last price, which happens to be at 11:00:00:

I tried searching and found this

```
SELECT * FROM `test_stock` t 
WHERE t.Date = (select MAX(Date) as MaxDate from test_stock tt where tt.Name = t.Name)
```

But this only returns the very latest data:

```
2021-04-27 11:00:00 Vestas  515
```

EDIT:
To make testing easier for you, I have added the DDL to create the data:

```
INSERT INTO test_stock (Date, Name, Price) VALUES ('2021-04-27 09:00:00', 'Vestas', 510);
INSERT INTO test_stock (Date, Name, Price) VALUES ('2021-04-27 10:00:00', 'Vestas', 520);
INSERT INTO test_stock (Date, Name, Price) VALUES ('2021-04-27 11:00:00', 'Vestas', 515);

INSERT INTO test_stock (Date, Name, Price) VALUES ('2021-04-26 09:00:00', 'Vestas', 495);
INSERT INTO test_stock (Date, Name, Price) VALUES ('2021-04-26 10:00:00', 'Vestas', 498);
INSERT INTO test_stock (Date, Name, Price) VALUES ('2021-04-26 11:00:00', 'Vestas', 480);

INSERT INTO test_stock (Date, Name, Price) VALUES ('2021-04-23 09:00:00', 'Vestas', 495);
INSERT INTO test_stock (Date, Name, Price) VALUES ('2021-04-23 10:00:00', 'Vestas', 487);
INSERT INTO test_stock (Date, Name, Price) VALUES ('2021-04-23 11:00:00', 'Vestas', 497);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `ROW_NUMBER`:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CAST(Date AS date) ORDER BY Date DESC) rn
    FROM test_stock
)

SELECT Date, Name, Price
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

If you're using an earlier version of MySQL:

```sql
SELECT ts1.Date, ts1.Name, ts1.Price
FROM test_stock ts1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT CAST(Date AS date) Date, MAX(Date) AS MaxDate
    FROM test_stock
    GROUP BY CAST(Date AS date)
) ts2
    ON ts2.Date = CAST(ts1.Date AS date) AND
       ts2.MaxDate = ts1.Date;
```

Comment: So sorry, I forgot to add it is MySQL :(

Comment: ...and that's not a problem if you're using MySQL 8+.

Comment: I have updated with a workaround.  Please consider upgrading to MySQL 8+ if you expect frequent requirements like this.

Answer (score 1):

The query mentioned in the question did not work because you were trying to match the whole `datetime` string, for which the max value is `2021-04-27 11:00:00`. What you needed was to match just the date part.

Also, it returned only one record because you were fetching only one date.
What you needed was max timestamp of each date for which you can group the records on the date part of the timestamp.

```
SELECT * FROM `test_stock` t 
WHERE t.Date in (select MAX(Date) as MaxDate from test_stock tt where tt.Name = t.Name group by Date(Date))
```

[DB-Fiddle Link for sample result](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kE3B7Jnz2XwFqRTHwF7iX8/1)

**Note**: Please try and avoid using the keywords as column name.

Comment: Please do test the solution. It does not return the desired output.

Comment: @doomdaam, Sorry, I misread the date part earlier. Have updated my answer along with a sample output.